# Copy data from MongoDB collection into a MySQL table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mongodb, database

I have a MySQL database with a table named **commit_files** that looks like this:

```
+----------+-------------+
| Field    | Type        |
+----------+-------------+
| sha      | varchar(40) |
| filename | text        | 
+----------+-------------+
```

The SHA column contains 50000 records, while the filename column is empty. I want to compare the SHA keys in this table with the SHA keys in a remote MongoDB collection.
The rule needs to be if the SHA exists in the Mongo collection, then pull the filename that corresponds with that SHA key and insert it into the filename field that corresponds with the SHA key in the local MySQL.

Currently the Java code I have iterates through all the data in the collection and inserts it into the MySQL database, however, due to the size of the MongoDB database it will not be efficient to pull everything as it will take a very long time.

I would like to get the filenames only for the SHA list I have in the MySQL, am I on the right track here? any ideas how to complete this would be great. Cheers

```js
//get commit files from mongo db and insert into mysql
DBCollection commits = db.getCollection("commits");

DBCursor commitList = commits.find();
System.out.println("Commits in MongoDB: " + commitList.size());
int handledCommit = 1;

while (commitList.hasNext()) {
  DBObject commit = commitList.next();

  String sha = commit.get("sha").toString();
  BasicDBList files = (BasicDBList) commit.get("files");
  if (files != null) {
    System.out.println("commit: " + handledCommit+++" files: " + files.size());
    for (Object f: files) {
      DBObject file = (DBObject) f;
      String filename = file.get("filename").toString();

      // insert into mysql

      String mysqlQuery = " insert into commit_files (sha, filename) values (?, ?)";
      PreparedStatement preparedStmt = mysqlConn.prepareStatement(mysqlQuery);
      preparedStmt.setString(1, sha);
      preparedStmt.setString(2, filename);
      preparedStmt.execute();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest, keep all your file names in an array. Do find with limit, say 100 at a time with sort by _id.

Keep 100th '_id' in some variable once you get the results. Next time use `$gt` in your find query to get more 100 results. I will show you find queries.

```
var arr = [Your sha values] //Keep proper value
var lastUid;

db.coll.find({sha:{'$in' : arr}}).limit(100).sort(_id : 1).toArray(function(err, results){ // results is an array of objects
    lastUid = results[100]._id;
})
```

After you are done with your code, you can try this following query:

```
db.coll.find({sha:{'$in' : arr}, _id:{$gt : lastUid}}).limit(100).sort(_id : 1).toArray(function(err, results){
    lastUid = results[100]._id;
})
```

See if this can help you.

I don't know Java, so written in javascript li'l bit.

EDIT:

You can keep the find part in one function and call it where you need.

Something like this also you can try:

```
var findQuery = {sha:{'$in' : arr}}, someMore;

if(lastUid) findQuery['$gt '] = lastUid;

db.coll.find().limit(100).sort(_id : 1).toArray(function(err, results){
    someMore = result[100]._id;
})
```